# Catch same exception multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is any way to continue executing `try` block if an exception is raised? I think that the aswer is no, but I think that the following code is ugly.

```
def preprocess(self, text):
    try:
        text = self.parser(text)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        terms = [term for term in text if term not in self.stopwords]
        text = list_to_string(terms)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        terms = [self.stemmer.stem(term) for term in text]
        text = list_to_string(terms)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return text
```

There is another way to do this in a pythonic form?

Comment: You can use the finally keyword [errors in python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Yes, but if do that there is a lot of nested code

Comment: Why all statement are not in one `try` section ?

Comment: @omri_saadon: yeah but the problem with that is that you do not know where the `try` has stopped and thus where to continue. The only solution would be to surround every statement with a `try`...

Comment: @Arman: well afaik the question is how to continue processing after an exception has been raised.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, If the exceptions were in a different kind, it could help.. just saying :)

Comment: @Arman I was thinking the same, considering in each `except`, there is just a `pass`? Maybe the pass is just being used for the example. I'm not really sure.

Comment: Why does `AttributeError` occur? You can check for `parser`, `stemmer` etc attributes

Comment: There are the same kind of execptions. If `parser`, `stopwords` or `stemmer` doesn't exist in the object, the call is `None.parser` for example

Comment: @DrZoo , Oh , I see.

Comment: use `hasattr` function

Comment: maybe with contextlib: `from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(AttributeError):`

Comment: @alexey "It is easier to ask for forgiveness than to ask permission"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, that's the aswer that I want :)

Comment: I like easy rep, but that answer is already in the link provided when I closed the question as duplicate. Sounded perfect for your need indeed :) enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite it in this way:

```
def preprocess(self, text):
    if hasattr(self, 'parser'): 
        text = self.parser(text)

    if hasattr(self, 'stopwords'): 
        terms = [term for term in text if term not in self.stopwords]
        text = list_to_string(terms)

    if hasattr(self, 'stemmer'):        
        terms = [self.stemmer.stem(term) for term in text]
        text = list_to_string(terms)

    return text
```

I think it's much easier to understand and would not catch `AttributeError` inside `parser` and `stem` calls

Comment: yes, it's better to avoid exceptions if possible. +1 for thinking outside the box of this duplicate question.